# Regular Expression to define a Regular Language

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

I need to write a regular expression for a regular language which its strings always start with 1 and have even number of 0s.

I have already tried ^1+(00)+(1|00)* in Java and it does accept strings like 100, 100100 , 10011001.. etc however it doesn't accept 10101010 while the number of 0s is even. any one with a better idea to define the regex, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
"^1+(01*01*)*$"
```

I'm assuming that only 0 and 1 are allowed, based on the regex you tried.  If you want to allow other characters:

```
"^1[^0]*(0[^0]*0[^0]*)*$"
```

Comment: @Lourin your answer will not accept strings like `"1"`, `"11111"`, etc.  Those have zero 0's, but zero is an even number.  If the requirement is that the number of 0's is at least 2, then your change is correct.

Comment: thanks for this. Yes 0s must appear in the strings (even number of times).

Answer (score 3):

> `I need to write a regular expression for a regular language which its strings always start with 1 and have even number of 0s.`

This lookahead based regex should work for you:

```
/^1(?=(([^0]*0){2})*[^0]*$)/

/^1(?=(([^0]*0){2})*[^0]*$)/.test('10'); // false
/^1(?=(([^0]*0){2})*[^0]*$)/.test('1000000'); // true
/^1(?=(([^0]*0){2})*[^0]*$)/.test('000000'); // false
```